# Why Google Adwords Conversation different from Google Console?

Tags: android, admob, google-ads-api

I'm using google AdWords for my android application promotion from last 2 years. From the last 4-5 days, my google AdWords campaign runs fast and spending much higher money then it use to be. And that conversion ration is not showing in google console and now even on my Admob. Like Google Adwords showing 9000 install and console says 3400 install from that same day. And no effect on AdMob also.

What happens to Google AdWords? Is any other facing this issue? What wrong I'm doing?

Comment: your question does not relate to software development, therefore is off-topic here.

Comment: then where i can go ?

Comment: google support probably. Not sure, but not here.

Comment: God does not exist, but it does not relate to the question. Please understand - StackOverflow is not the place to ask for any question that you did not found other place to ask. It has it's topics and types of questions that are on-topic. It is not designed as a charity place to help the people in need. It is a database of Q&A for software-development questions, and asking non-related questions harms StackOverflow structure.

Comment: you are going to get banned if you don't stop this flood.